# Odata/Web Api Erron on Azure Website "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor"

Tags: c#, azure, odata

I got this from azure website after deployment when accessing the api. it works perfectly fine on local.

**An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ItemController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.**

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ItemController'. **Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.**</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext()</StackTrace><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>**Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest**.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.BadImageFormatException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at RecycleMeOdataWebApi.Controllers.ItemController..ctor()
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>

  public partial class ItemController : ODataController
{
    public ItemController()
    {
    }
    private RecycleMeContext db = new RecycleMeContext();

    // GET odata/Item
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Item> GetItem()
    {
        return db.Items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You controller simply lacks of a parameterless public constructor.

Just add:

```
public ItemController() 
{
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: i have added the code. its weird cause there are two errors "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies"